# Extract words from observations in one column to new columns in R

Tags: r, gsub, stringr

Below is a hypothetical dataframe.

```
Category <- c("Male children 0-15 years", "Female children 0-15 years", "Male Youths 18 years",  "Female Youths 18 years")
value <- c(12, 23, 33, 45)
DF <- data.frame(Category, value)

                   Category value
1   Male children 0-15 years    12
2 Female children 0-15 years    23
3       Male Youths 18 years    33
4     Female Youths 18 years    45
```

I'd like to split the observations in the column `Category` into two, the first word and the rest of the words so that my final dataframe looks like this

```
                    Category gender value          new.column
1   Male children 0-15 years   Male    12 children 0-15 years
2 Female children 0-15 years Female    23 children 0-15 years
3       Male Youths 18 years   Male    33     Youths 18 years
4     Female Youths 18 years Female    45     Youths 18 years
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tidyr::separate`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
DF %>% 
  separate(Category, into = c("gender", "new.column"), remove = FALSE, extra = "merge")
```